# How to run sqlite3 on ESP8266 using lua firmware?

Tags: sqlite, lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I want to run sqlite3 on ESP8266 using nodemcu lua firmware. I build the firmware using linux but unable to run sqlite3 over ESP8266. I got an error 'sqlite3' module not found.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry for the trouble. You currently would have to modify the firmware code in a few places.

Please see https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues/2913 for details. If you can contribute to that issue with insights it would be appreciated.

Comment: Is any alternate way to store data locally in ESP8266.

Comment: SPIFFS file system?